# How display download progress of file in notification bar using xamarin forms?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

1. I'm creating dependency service to download file from the URL in xamarin forms.
2. I can able to download the multiple documents simultaneously in app. But the only problem is i need to display the download status in notification bar. Can any one suggest me or provide simple xamarin forms app where you downloading the document in background

Thanks,
Sathish

Answer (score -2):

You made simple `ProgressBar`. At starts set its progress to zero. Then on every byte downloaded change its value by formula.

```
progress = (bytes downloaded / total size ) * 100.
```

Then set this updated value to your progress in this way your progress bar will be updated. Let me know if you get the idea.

Comment: I need to display download progress in notification in xamarin forms